# "Exception has occurred: error" in cv2.imshow

Tags: python, opencv

I just tried to make simple computer vision code that copied from some website using python 3.6.6 and openCV4.1.0 but there's an error,what is my fault?

in every "cv2.imshow" there's always has some error

```py
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

cv2.namedWindow("test")

img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)
    if not ret:
        break
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Escape hit, closing...")
        break
    elif k%256 == 32:
        # SPACE pressed
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it should compile as webcam view on my laptop.
but this is what i got:

```
Exception has occurred: error
OpenCV(4.1.0) ../modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

Answer (score 2):

The key here is to remember that whenever you perform a `cv2.imshow()` operation inside a `while True` cycle, the following structure has to be used:

```
while True: 
    r, f = cam.read()
    if r: 
        cv2.imshow("f", f)
        if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            break
```

Then you can build all your application logic around this basic structure.

Comment: yes but it just generate next error in     if k%256 == 27:
File "/home/mecha/coba2.py", line 16
    if k%256 == 27:
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Than, by all means, read some basic tutorials about Python. IndentationError means exactly that, a block is not indented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your error

> size.width>0 && size.height>0

tells you that either the width or the height of your image is zero. This means that`frame` is not valid and can not be shown. Check that your `frame` is valid before showing.

The good thing is that `cam.read()` already tells you if the reading was successful as can be read in the [documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#capture-video-from-camera) (`cap` is equal to your `cam`):

> cap.read() returns a bool (True/False). If frame is read correctly, it
>   will be True. So you can check end of the video by checking this return value.

The actual reading and showing should look like this:

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:   # frame is valid
        # show the frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
```

Full Example using your code:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # adjusted to the first device '0'
img_counter = 0

while(True):
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if ret:   # frame is valid
        # show the frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key & 0xFF == ord('s'): # s for saving
            print("S hit, saving...")
            img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
            print("{} written!".format(img_name))
            img_counter += 1
        if key & 0xFF == ord('q'): # q for quitting
            print("Q hit, closing...")
            break
    else:
        print("Frame not valid")          
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If all your frames are invalid (video device not working) it will print

> 'Frame not valid'

the whole time to show you that something is wrong.
I adjusted the parameter of `VideoCapture` to use the first video device of your system (counting starts at 0 not 1).
The Example uses 's' for saving and 'q' for quitting.

Comment: How do i write it?

Comment: unfortunately not yet :(

Comment: @marshallalkarim I added a full example to my answer, try that one out.

Comment: wrong,i get new probs Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'true' is not defined

Comment: Ok. I fixed the typo but now I am out of this discussion... I think it would be best to read some basic Python tutorials before tackling harder problems like image processing. Without understanding the very basics it will be very hard to fix problems on your own or get a good understanding of how something works.